# yii custom query and CSqlDataProvider

Tags: sql, yii, ranking

Could someone let me know how to run this query with CSqlDataProvider(yii framework (php ))

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, fruit, amount


FROM sales
 ORDER BY amount DESC
;
```

and I can do it like below , but

```
$sqlProvider = new CSqlDataProvider('
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, nameAndFam
  FROM user
');
```

cant initialise `SET @rank=0;` before above command ..

I want to rank my select  and I think its the good way 
thanks in advance for your reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use YII createcommnd from Database Access OBject (DAO) which will provide lowest level of working with database which you can create any queries from any kinds.

```
$sql1 = 'SET @rank=0;';
$sql2 = 'SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, fruit, amount
    FROM sales
     ORDER BY amount DESC';
$cmd1 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql1);
$cmd2 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql2);

$cmd1->execute();
$result = $cmd2->query();
```

after that you can use a foreach loop to loop through the object array returned  from this query

you can create create separate function such as:

```
$cmd->select ='SELECT @rank:=@rank+1';
```

that way will make the code so much readable but since you only needed to have this work I only provided you the pure, not optimized way.
Hope this may help you work it out.